# What would my update statement look like if I want to update data in a column to just the first 250 characters?

Tags: sql

What would my update statement look like if I want to update data in a column to just the first 250 characters?

Comment: It would include substring

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do, could you give an example (provide the record before the operation, and the record after operation) ?

Comment: It would look like an update statement, but with some string manipulation on a value to get just a substring of that value.

Comment: Also which SQL vendor are you using?

Comment: So I need to take the values that have more than 250 characters and truncate to just the first 250. I tried "Update table set column = LEFT(colummn,250) where column in ('xxx', yyyy') It didnt like the LEFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the SUBSTR function.

```
UPDATE table
SET column = SUBSTR(column, 1, 250)
WHERE column IN ('xxx', 'yyy');
```

I've written about [SUBSTR before for Oracle](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-substr/), but it's an SQL standard function so should work pretty much the same for other databases.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will give that a try tomorrow and let you know.